# Jquery load() and colorbox() together

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox, jquery-load

I am trying to load a part of the page using jQuery load function and display it using colorbox. I am currently using

```
       $(document).ready(function()
       {
          $(".rest-menuitem a").click(function(event) 
          {
                event.preventDefault();
                var elementURL = $(this).attr("href");
                $.colorbox({ html: $.load(elementURL+ " .product" ) , width:'1000px',height:'80%', href: finalURL);
});
});
```

This is not working because we need to have a selector for load function. Is there a way to solve my problem using load? If not is there a alternative solution?

Comment: Have you tried [.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) in place of .load()

Comment: .get() function does not filter the part of the page. Since I don't need the entire page.

Comment: Well, you can quite easily filter it yourself... the .load() method loads all the page filter afterwards.

Comment: load() doesn't really filter either, it just does a bit of the work for you by grabbing a smaller portion of the response and loading it into your target.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you looking after is the [.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) method. It loads data from the specified url and executes a callback when data is available. You can then filter the received html yourself and use your colorbox plugin.

Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".rest-menuitem a").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.get($(this).attr("href"), function(data) {
            $.colorbox({
                html: $(data).find('.product'),
                width: '1000px',
                height: '80%',
                href: finalURL);
            });
        });;
    });
});
```

Comment: I set the height to false, allowing the box to become the right height, but I'm finding it's setting the height too soon, before the inner content has loaded. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can either start opening the colorbox before or after the ajax information returns. Before probably makes more sense for the user, after is easier to adapt your code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".rest-menuitem a").click(function(event) 
    {
        var elementURL = $(this).attr("href");
        var $html = $('<div />');
        $.when( $html.load(elementURL+ " .product" ) ).done(function(){
            $.colorbox({ html: $html.html() , width:'1000px',height:'80%', href: finalURL);
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

When you click, this will ajax in your content to a div which is unattached to the DOM. When that ajax completes it will fire a colorbox and populate it with the contents of the homeless div. Eloquent? no. But it's the closest solution to what you're already doing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, from your question, that you are trying to load part of an external page into a colorbox. I didn't think that was possible with $.get().

I had to do this for a client and this is the solution I came up with:

```
$('.popup-link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var url = $(this).attr('href').replace('#', ' #');

    $('body').append('<div id="ajax-load-element-wrapper" style="display:none;"><div id="ajax-load-element" style="padding: 20px;"></div></div>');

    $('#ajax-load-element').load(url, function() {
        $.colorbox({
            href: '#ajax-load-element',
            width: 600,
            height: 400,
            inline: true,
            opacity: .7
        });
    }); 
});
```

This will automatically separate the element within the URL, as required by the $.load() function.

This means that you can maintain graceful degradation by using URLs like this in your  tags:

```
/test.html#div
```

Since the JS will automatically add a space before the #div, as required by $.load().